# Would people like a Flash to C# Converter?

Tags: c#, flash

I am wondering if there is much demand for a Flash to C# Converter. It would convert all the assets and code from a swf, and output .png/.mp3/.avi and .cs files, so you can then compile them.

You would input the swf, choose a few options, then it will do it's thing. I would probably make it that you could target it for Desktop/DX, Desktop/OpenGL(for Mac and Linux), Mobile/Win7, Mobile/MonoTouch.

I have managed to read through the swf file format, and have gotten useful information from it.

So, my point is this: it is going to take a while to write, and will be a big task. Should I go ahead with this project, or find something more useful.

Comment: Good idea..How about flash to silverlight? i would really use a tool like this. And probably silverlight to flash?

Comment: I could do flash to silverlight(probably), but the problem with converting .Net Bytecode to any other language(JVM, or Flash) is that .net supports a lot of things that the other ones don't, such as structs and generics(though I think JVM does that now).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go for it. Especially if you open source it, the programming and end-user world could possibly only be a better place because of it.

Caveat: read the copyright stuff *carefully*. Even Java, which many used to believe was more or less open, showed that it was not infinitely so when Google created some of their own Java runtime for Android.

Comment: I was planning on releasing it under the MIT license, or something similar.

Comment: @Programmdude: Regardless of what you release it under, Dinah is trying to say that you need to check what the copyright around the SWF format is.  If Adobe is highly restrictive about decompiling flash files then you might not want to do this project.

Comment: @Chris: in fairness to the OP, I answered with only the 1st paragraph above, then Programmdude commented, then I added my caveat. Programmdude's comment was in response to "Especially if you open source it"

Comment: @Dinah: Ahh, I missed the update because SO coalesce's them within a certain timeframe. ;)

Comment: In June 2009, Adobe launched the Open Screen Project (Adobe link), which made the SWF specification available without restrictions. Previously, developers could not use the specification for making SWF-compatible players, but only for making SWF-exporting authoring software. The specification still omits information on codecs such as Sorenson Spark, however.[54] ^ "Free Flash community reacts to Adobe Open Screen Project". http://www.openmedianow.org/?q=node/21. Retrieved 2008-11-29.

Comment: It should be fine, I found the above thing on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 1):

Why convert it to C# at all?  Just convert the swf to an IL assembly and be done with it.  Emitting IL is slightly more complicated than emitting C# text, but not as difficult as you might think, especially if you're coming from another VM where most of your work will be mapping the Flash VM opcodes and types onto IL opcodes and types.

Comment: I though about that, and for some reason I decided to go with converting to code. I will have to look into it more when I get home.

Comment: @dthorpe: I believe this is a matter of preference. The OP obviously wants to see the C# code. So either his app can emit IL and use Reflector to see the C# or you can compile his C# to get the IL. 6 of one 1/2 dozen of the other.

Comment: @Dinah: In terms of usefulness to users, I'd rather have a one-step convert SWF to IL than a multistep process to convert to C#, then leave it to the user to figure out how to compile the C# into something useful.  People who might be interested in converting SWF to something else probably includes non-programmers.

Comment: There's also the observation that C# syntax does not define the .NET platform.  IL supports operations that C# syntax does not.

Comment: @dthorpe: that's a reasonable request. In the end, I won't criticize whichever way Programmdude decides to go. If he's doing all of this crazy legwork, I'll be more than happy to use Reflector to get my desired language back out of it if it's in IL. I'll be equally happy to hit 'build' if it's in C#.

Comment: You all have good points, and it is probably just as easy to export it in IL, probably using AssemblyBuilder. I havn't done that much work with AssemblyBuilder, or IL in general before. But I suppose that its all a learning experience.

Answer (score 1):

I've written a SWF generator, and I personally think you're in over your head. With all due respect, enormous kudos if you can do this, but the flash file format is very versatile. How i.e. would you handle morphing (tweening)? I agree with the other people here that says that a silverlight converter is probably a better product, and again I'll be very impressed if you can pull this one off.

Comment: Well, I am starting with the AVM2 bytecode, and will work on the other aspects(Such as Morphing/Tweening and all that) later. I agree that it will be quite difficult, but a challenge is probably something that I need right now.

Comment: I'd be interested in following this project. Are you gonna create a webpage or blog for the program? In any case hit me up on peder(a)bit-kit.com and maybe I can help.

Comment: I was going to make a CodePlex page for it, but after I can successfully decompile a Hello World program.

Comment: I look forward to see your progress!